# Can Indian citizens obtain visas on arrival in Dubai?

Tags: indian-citizens, dubai

My Flight is on 25th June 2019 and I'm travelling from Guatemala to India but I want to stay in Dubai to visit my cousins over there and back to India.

I'm an Indian Citizen.

Do we get visa on arrival or we need to travel with the visa??

Because my friends travelled through Dubai and stayed over there for 15days and they got on arrival visa and just to confirm before booking the Tickets.

Answer (score 1):

**You can only get visa on arrival if you already have a US visa or a green card.**

According to [this Emirates page](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visas/index.aspx), Indian nationals are not on the list of nationalities eligible for UAE visa on arrival. However, there's an exception which may be relevant:

> As of 1 May 2017, Indian nationals holding a normal passport valid for a minimum of six months from the arrival date, and a **visit visa or green card issued by the USA** which is valid for a minimum of six months, can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 14 days for a charge of AED120 (subject to change). They can apply to extend their stay for an additional 14 days for AED250 (subject to change).